# Phonegap and geofencing

Tags: cordova, geolocation

A client ask me to build an App in phonegap, the principle is that the user's geolocation  will trigger a specific questionnaire. And the correct answer will produce a new location to go and the new location a new questionnaire etc....

Is there a way to that in phonegap, or it's a native thing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in PhoneGap. You'd need to call [Geolocation.watchPosition](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.watchPosition) to track where you are at. In the success callback to watchPosition you'd compare the result to the location you are expecting.